# Display WHERE condition values that match in selected fields

Tags: mysql, sql, eloquent

Let's consider that I have a table named **Citizens** containing these fields and values :

```
| ID | Name   | Age |
|----|:------:|---: |
| 1  | King   | 60  |
| 2  | Queen  | 50  |
| 3  | Prince | 25  |
```

If I want to display citizens who are between "**50** and **100**" years old and others who are between "**5** and **30**", I could use a simple **WHERE** condition like this :

```
SELECT * FROM Citizens WHERE (Age BETWEEN 5 AND 30 ) OR (Age BETWEEN 50 AND 100 );
```

But, here comes the question : how to display **minimal and maximal** requested ages beside each row that match conditions to have something like this?

```
| ID | Name   | Age |INTERVAL|
|----|:------:|:---:|-------:|
| 1  | King   | 60  | 50-100 |
| 2  | Queen  | 50  | 50-100 |
| 3  | Prince | 25  |  5-30  |
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Age,
    CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 5 AND 30 THEN '5-30'
         WHEN Age BETWEEN 50 AND 100 THEN '50-100'
         ELSE 'OTHER' END AS INTERVAL
FROM Citizens
WHERE (Age BETWEEN 5 AND 30) OR (Age BETWEEN 50 AND 100);
```

Note: I'm not sure whether you only want to display certain age ranges.  If so, then leave your current `WHERE` clause intact.  If instead you want to include all data, then remove the `WHERE` clause.  In this case, non matching ranges would be reported as `OTHER`.

Another approach which might scale better would be to have an interval table:

```
start | end | interval
5     | 30  | 5-30
50    | 100 | 50-100
```

Then join to this table to bring in the interval label:

```
SELECT c.Id, c.Name, c.Age, i.interval
FROM Citizens c
INNER JOIN interval i
    ON c.Age BETWEEN i.start AND i.end
WHERE (c.Age BETWEEN 5 AND 30) OR (c.Age BETWEEN 50 AND 100);
```

One major possible advantage of this second approach is that it might be possible to bring in an index strategy.

Comment: ... and now Tim beats me.

Comment: It can work but let's consider that we do have a lot of intervals to research through, won't this proposal produce some huge/long query?

Comment: @CfassKing Check my updated answer for a join option which avoids the `CASE` expression.

Comment: Ok, I'll be testing it using **temporary table** and I'll come back after. Thanks.

Comment: Before that, what about using an **SQL FUNCTION**?

Comment: Thank you, @TimBiegeleisen , I used your second approach. "Interval" table equivalent has been stored into **temporary table**.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT
  id, name, age,
  case when age between 5 and 30 then '5-30' else '50-100' end as interval
FROM Citizens
WHERE (Age BETWEEN 5 AND 30 ) OR (Age BETWEEN 50 AND 100 );
```

Comment: Thanks, mistyped.

Comment: It can work but let's consider that we do have a lot of intervals to research through, won't this proposal produce some huge/long query?

Comment: Yes, it will. I don't see any solution more concise than this one, unless the intervals are stored in a separate table, as in Tim's solution.

Comment: What about using an **SQL FUNCTION**?

Comment: A SQL function will still need to enumerate all cases. I don't see any saving in typing. Your SQL will look [articitially] shorter, though.